# Is there a way to compress the TIFF format file in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, tiff, jpeg

Is there any way, we can decrease the size of TIFF image without losing the quality? I am working on a TIFF image in Photoshop, and it's actually taking a lifetime to open and share the file.

Is there anyway in Photoshop to convert it to JPEG — or at least reduce the size of tiff file?

Comment: First place to look is always Adobe Help… available from the Help Menu. https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/photoshop/using/saving-files-graphics-formats.html BTW, it will take longer to open a compressed format, as it has to uncompress on the fly.

Comment: Interestingly, I just saved the same file with no comp, LZW & ZIP; they came out 144MB, 156MB & 120MB - bizarrely the LZW was the largest of the three. ZIP isn't supported in older apps. Of the three, only the ZIP took more than one second to open.

Comment: To convert to jpg.. open, save as....

Comment: FYI Tiff is, by nature, a compressed format.

Answer (score 0):

You have several things happening here.

Yes, the file size could be an issue on the time it takes to open or save a file. But this is also the case when compressing it, so, a fast way to open a file is not compressing it.

So, let's assume you need to actually compress the file without losing information. Choose a lossless compression algorithm like ZIP.

> Is there anyway in Photoshop to convert it to jpeg

Open the file, and save it as JPG.

But you stated before that you do not want a "quality loss" I do not use the term of quality but information. With JPG you will lose information. So, define what you really need to do.

> lifetime to open and share the file

This could be your internet connection speed. And a lifetime is not an objective measuring unit. A specific size in Mb could be more useful.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ctrl(cmd) + shift + alt + s ("Save for Web" window opens)
2. Choose the format you want.

[image]

If the file is still too large you also can play with quality:

[image]

Or Image size:

[image]

You also can check the layers in a tiff. And merge everything you can and check the doc size if you want to keep that format. If jpg works for you just save it "for web" here is two ways how you can do it from the menu:

[image]